# Can't open .avi and np.array video frames in streamlit

Tags: python, video, avi, streamlit

can not open videos with `.avi` format in `streamlit.video()`

> ```py
> video_bytes = open(video_address, 'rb').read()
> st.video(video_bytes)
> ```

output:
[image: blank frame for video but not playing anything]

I've tried other formats like `.mp4` and `.H264` and even `numpy.array` of the target video frames, but it doesn't work.

any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Might be due to the fact that streamlit video uses the HTML5 video player that does not support some default mp4 codecs.

The workaround[1] is to use the H264 codec which is supported by the HTML5 video player, and to convert my existing mp4 video into that codec using ffmpeg.

```
ffmpeg -i input_video_created_by_OpenCV.mp4 -vcodec libx264 output_video_that_streamlit_can_play.mp4
```

[1]https://github.com/streamlit/streamlit/issues/1580